# PowerShell Maintainig the order of a DataTable in PSObject

Tags: powershell, datatable, hashtable, import-from-excel

I'm trying to import an excel sheet and it works fine. However, the order of the columns is not kept. For example text that is written in the first column is being output as the second Property instead of the first.

**Example input file:**

```
ServerName   | First name | Last name
C:\Drive     | Bob        | Johnson
```

The example above gives the following output as `PSObject`, which is incorrect as it's not in the same order as the file above is. It should start with the ServerName first, instead of:

```
First name : Bob
ServerName : C:\Drive
Last name  : Johnson
```

**The code:**

```
Function Import-Excel {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [String]$FileName, 
        [String]$WorksheetName
    )

    Process {
        $OleDbConnection = New-Object 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection'
        $OleDbCommand    = New-Object 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand'
        $OleDbAdapter    = New-Object 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter'
        $DataTable       = New-Object 'System.Data.DataTable'

        $ConnString = 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='
        $ConnString += $FileName
        $ConnString += ';Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";'          
        $OleDbConnection.ConnectionString = $ConnString
        $OleDbConnection.Open()
        $OleDbCommand.Connection = $OleDbConnection
        $OleDbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [$WorksheetName$]"
        $OleDbAdapter.SelectCommand = $OleDbCommand
        $OleDbAdapter.Fill($DataTable) | Out-Null
        $OleDbConnection.Close()

        $columnArray = @()
        foreach ($Col in $DataTable.Columns.ColumnName) {
            $ColumnArray += $Col.toString()
        }
        $returnObject = @()
        foreach ($Ro in $DataTable.Rows) {
            $i=0;
            $rowObject = @{}
            foreach ($colu in $Ro.ItemArray) {
                $rowObject += @{$columnArray[$i]=$colu.toString()}
                $i++
            } 
            $returnObject += New-Object PSObject -Property $rowObject
        }
        return $returnObject
    }
}
```

I've tried so far by using an `ArrayList` instead. This works fine to keep the order of the input correct, but `New-Object PSObject` does not accept an `ArrayList` as input.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264752/hash-tables-in-powershell).

It appears to be possible to have an **Ordered** hashtable:

```
$rowObject = [Ordered]@{}
```